# How to import GitHub repository to Intellij?

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea

I have a repository (Java project) in GitHub created in Eclipse.

When I import this repository to my local eclipse everything works fine.

But when I import the same repository to IntelliJ, then I'm not able to RUN of CREATE any class.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: how did you import it in IntelliJ? Is it a maven or gradle project?

Comment: Make sure source roots and content roots are configured inside the Java module. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#add-new-module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the running configuration.
You can do it quickly by finding the `main` method and click and the arrow to create the configuration and launch it.

[image: Create run configuration (form jetbrains.com)]

If you have to pass some arguments then, learn more about running in IntelliJ [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html).

Comment: I know how to RUN classes. The problem is RUN is not active. In your picture, you have a green triangle on the left of the main method, but I do not have it. Also RUN button on the panel is not active. I think the problem is because the project was created in eclipse and now I imported it to IntelliJ. Intellij sees it like a folder with files instead of the JAVA project.